# Angular 10 append X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest to the header

Tags: angular, header, angular-services

I wrote an angular service that calls an old API.  I need to format the header to look like the following, where the 'X-Requested-With' shows at the bottom (this is a requirement, not by choice). Here's an image of the original request:

[image]

Here's is a snippet of my code, which does run and returns a status of 200:

```
  private _headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; 
   charset=UTF-8');
  myRequest(data: string): Observable<string> {
    return this.http.post<string>(this.url, data, { headers: this._headers });
  }
```

What is correct way to append the X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest to the header.  Thanks for the help. This is an image of what I get so far:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HttpHeaders in Angular are immutable](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpHeaders)

This means you can set your `X-Requested-With` header in your `myRequest` function.

```js
myRequest(data: string): Observable<string> {
  const headers = this._headers.set('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
  return this.http.post<string>(this.url, data, { headers });
}
```

It won't change your `private _headers`.

You can [inspect the headers in this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bk7cpp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)